# Is synchronization necessary with only one thread

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety

If I have a class that extends Thread with static methods on it (this is very simplified):

```
public class MyThread extends Thread {

    private static long SLEEP_INT = 30000;
    private static Map<Integer, String> myData;

    //every 30 seconds, update map of data
    public void run() {
        while(isActive) {
            try {
                populateDataFromDB();
                Thread.sleep( SLEEP_INT );
            }
            catch( Exception e ) {
                //do nothing
            }
        }
    }

    //static method to update map of data
    public static void populateDataFromDB() {
        //do stuff here, setting values in myData
    }
}
```

and then somewhere else in my application I have:

```
MyThread.populateDataFromDB();
```

If I know that there is only one instance of the *MyThread* class in my application, is it still necessary to write synchronized code inside of *populateDataFromDB* in order to ensure thread safety?

Comment: Why is `populateDataFromDB` static in the first place?  Shouldn't it be an instance method?

Comment: Can you be absolutely sure that you will only every have one instance, now and forever, as your code evolves?

Comment: @weschneider the thread is used as a caching mechanism so that a db call is not needed in every servlet. In realty the run method has additional logic so it doesn't pull unless the data is stale. The populateDataFromDB needs to be static because there is one other spot in the application that needs to force a re-populate without having reference to the thread.

Comment: Synchronization is useless with 1 thread. The real question is how can you be sure that only one thread will call `populateDataFromDB` since the following code is possible: `new MyThread().start(); MyThread.populateDataFromDB();` ?

Comment: @AndyTurner yes, the thread is initialized (and started) on application start. There is no need to have additionally threads since the only purpose to store "global" data throughout the application.

Comment: But as both @Spotted and I am alluding, what's to *actually stop* you creating another one?

Comment: @Spotted There are some aspects of threading I don't quite understand yet. There is only one spot in the application that calls    new MyThread().start();    and it is only called on when the application is first started. There are multiple spots that    MyThread.populateDataFromDB();   is called

Comment: @uesports135 As you said, if you call `MyThread.populateDataFromDB()` **at the same moment** when your background thread is calling `populateDataFromDB()`, this could corrupt `MyData`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do need synchronization, because you will have more than one thread that is accessing the data held in `MyThread.myData`. You have shown us one thread, which is going to periodically read from your database and fill in your Map. You would only do this if you have something that is going to utilize this data.

You do not want the threads that use the Map to ever see a half-filled map, or a map that contains inconsistent state. To be safe, you would want to use synchronization to keep threads from reading `myData` while the `MyThread` thread is updating it every 30 seconds.

In other words, just because you only have one instance of a given class doesn't necessarily mean that you do not need synchronization. You need synchronization because you have multiple threads (each perhaps running different code) that are accessing the same data. You probably can allow all the readers of the data to access the data at the same time, but ensure exclusive access during the operation that writes to the data structure.

Answer (score 2):

No, you never need synchronization when you have only one thread. (And main thread is the first thread in the application)

BUT When you do thread.start from your main thread, then you have 2 threads in your system. If for some reason your threads (new and main thread) are trying write a on memory which both threads have access to, then you want to serialize the access of threads on that shared memory. How to serialize the access is where synchronization helps.

So in your example if populateDataFromDB tries to modify that shared data and I assume that you may calling this from the new thread (inside run)and you also want to access that populateDataFromDB from main thread(I assumed that as you said "then somewhere else in my application I have:"), then you definitely needs synchronization.